# bind data to select using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a trouble when bind data to form using AngularJS. I use ajax to get book's info and all categories from database and assign to variable $scope in controller. Some fields have been bind to form but field category_id can not set selected.

This is my controller

```
gridApp.controller('editCtrl',function($scope,$parse,$http,$routeParams,$location,BookService){
$http({
    url: base_url + 'angular/get-books',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {id:$routeParams.id}
}).then(function(response){
    $scope.book = response.data;
});

$http.get(base_url + 'angular/get-categories').then(function(response){
    $scope.categories = response.data;
});

$scope.save = function(){
    BookService.save($scope.book).success(function(response){
        if(response.success){
            $location.path('/index');
        }else{
            angular.forEach(response.message,function(msg,field){
                field = field.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + field.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                var  errorField = 'error'+field;
                $parse(errorField).assign($scope,msg);
            })
        }
    });
}});
```

This is my config code

```
gridApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
$routeProvider
    .when('/index',{ templateUrl: base_url + 'assets/partials/index.html', controller: 'datagridCtrl' })
    .when('/create',{ templateUrl: base_url + 'assets/partials/form.html', controller: 'createCtrl' })
    .when('/edit/:id',{ templateUrl: base_url + 'assets/partials/form.html', controller: 'editCtrl' })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' })}]);
```

This is my view code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorName }">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="book.name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"/>
                <p class="help-block" ng-show="errorName">{{ errorName }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Category</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="book.category_id" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in categories track by item.id">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : errorPrice }">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Price</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" ng-model="book.price" placeholder="Price" class="form-control"/>
                <p class="help-block" ng-show="errorPrice">{{ errorPrice }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Special</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="special" ng-model="book.special" value="1"/> Yes 
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="special" ng-model="book.special" value="0"/> No
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="book.description" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <button ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is result after binding data to form
[binding data to form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t013.jpg)

Please help solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ng-options directive, I suggest you to use ng-repeat directive for the select control .

You can find the difference between ng-repeat and ng-options.

ng-repeat creates a new scope for each iteration so will not perform as well as ng-options.

For small lists, it will not matter, but larger lists should use ng-options. Apart from that, It provides lot of flexibility in specifying iterator and offers performance benefits over ng-repeat.